# How to get Nginx to use alternative PHP version?

Tags: php, nginx

I have an Ubuntu web server running Nginx. I was runngin PHP 5.5.30 and I installed PHP 5.6.23 using the following commands:

```
1) sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
2) sudo apt-get update
3) sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

The installation is under a new path from the previous verison of PHP (/etc/php/5.6/). When I run a phpinfo() command from a web page I still get it running under the old version of PHP (5.5.30) - how do I get Nginx looking at the new installation?

p.s. When I run php --version from the command line it show PHP 5.6.23 !
p.p.s My nginx.conf file contains `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;`

Comment: [This](http://serverfault.com/a/671849) post might help.

Comment: My .sock file does not seem to be in the location that is specified in the file /etc/php/5.6/fpm/pool.d/www.conf, which is currently set to /run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock - what do I do now ?

Comment: Have you installed `php5.6-fpm`? Try `sudo apt-get install php5.6-fpm`

Comment: Yeah, I  had installed this version. Now I am getting Permission denied while connecting to upstream "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock" error.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show how you are writing your `fastcgi_pass` directive under `location` in your configuration file?

Comment: Done - fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have the same problem. You forgot to change the default sockets from `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;` to `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;` - you can find the configuration file at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`.

**Before:**

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
```

**After:**

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to replace `/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock` by a symbolic link that points to `/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;` ?

Comment: @Barthy Not if you want to use multiple versions of PHP

Comment: I have amazon linux. And there i am not able to find /etc/nginx/sites-available/ path. What is relevant file to change on that OS?