# Can php-fpm use php55 instead of php?

Tags: php

I have php duel-installed on my Centos (7) system. One is php 4.5, and this is invoked using the normal "php" command. I also have php 5.5 installed as "php55".

My web service uses nginx and php-fpm to run an app built with php. I now want php-fpm to use php55 instead of php. Is that possible? I've looked through the php-fpm configuration, and there does not seem to be an option for this.

Any advice?

Comment: I know sqwat about nginx, but with apache i can pick which php library to load as the php handler.  Look in your nginx config, make certain you point to the proper phpXX.so library.  ps: nowadays, for many if not most, the `normal` php is 8.x ! :)

Comment: This question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014106/how-to-get-nginx-to-use-alternative-php-version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Nginx to use alternative PHP version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014106/how-to-get-nginx-to-use-alternative-php-version)