# How to change php version to 8 in Laravel Forge server?

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04, laravel-forge

Ubuntu 18.04. Nginx.

The server used to be hosted by Laravel Forge. Now - no, in free swimming. There were no changes on the server - everything that was created and configured by Forge remained.

I see the PHP 8.1 version is installed along the path /usr/bin/*php8.1. How can I change the php version now? Directly on the server without the Forge web interface. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Nginx to use alternative PHP version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014106/how-to-get-nginx-to-use-alternative-php-version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Terminal

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

will display all versions installed, choose a number selection if you want a version

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative php (providing /usr/bin/php).

  Selection    Path             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/php8.0   80        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/php7.2   72        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/php7.4   74        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/php8.0   80        manual mode

Press "enter" to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php7.4 to provide /usr/bin/php (php) in manual mode
```

> check current php version

```
php --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your server and click PHP from the menu on the left. Scroll down on the page and click “Install” on the desired version.
Here is complete way if you want[enter link description here](https://laravel-forge-menubar.com/articles/update-phpversion-laravel-forge#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20your%20server%20and,Install%E2%80%9D%20on%20the%20desired%20version.)

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I need to make changes directly on the server without using Forge's web interface. Because the server was configured using Forge, but now the Forge web interface is not used, but the server remains. But I don't know where Laravel Forge changes PHP versions on the server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).